# Cannot find module 'ui/frame'

Tags: nativescript, ui

Estoy iniciando con `apps` moviles en `NativeScript`, y tengo un boton de primera que la presionar debe de cambiarme de pantalla

codigo `xml`:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo">
    <ActionBar title="My App" icon="" />
    <StackLayout class="p-20">
<Button text="Cambiar de pantalla" tap="{{ Cambio }}" class="-primary"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Main-view-model.js:

```
const Observable = require("@nativescript/core").Observable;
function createViewModel() {
  const viewModel = new Observable()
  viewModel.Cambio = () => {
    var navigationEntry = {
        moduleName: "/Sumar/suma",
        animation: true,
        transition: {
            name: "slide",
            duration: 380,
            curve: "easeIn"
        }
    };
    var frameModule = require("ui/frame");
    var topmost = frameModule.topmost();
    topmost.navigate(navigationEntry);
};
  return viewModel
}

exports.createViewModel = createViewModel;
```

Carpeta nueva pantalla:

Cree una nueva carpeta con sus respectivo archivos, y una pregunta para esta parte es porque se pintan de color verde??????

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En fin... cuando ejecuto la app me marca este error de `UI`, que no tengo conocimiento de que se refiere
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estoy suponiendo que el mensaje de error no comienza donde muestra la imagen. Podías incluir el mensaje de error exacto, como texto (puedes igual sustitur las carpetas que no quieres que se vean por un valor xxx).

Comment: El color verde suele indicar que el fichero es nuevo y se va a añadir al repositorio en el siguiente commit

Answer (score 0):

Parece que no encuentra la carpeta `node_modules` en el directorio raíz del proyecto. En consola, ingresa al directorio que contiene el archivo `package.json` de tu proyecto y escribe lo siguiente:

```
npm install
```

Como dijo Pablo en los comentarios, los archivos y directorios recién creados se iluminan con verde. Los modificados con amarillo y los eliminados con rojo. Tiene que ver con el versionamiento de Git que utiliza tu IDE.